# How to add to git binary file, which has both CRLF and LF symbols inside?

Tags: git, binaryfiles, eol

I try to add GIF image to repository, but git translates CRLF symbols to LF, so image is broken inside repository. I tried to set `core.autocrlf = false` and `core.safecrlf = true`, but all I've got now is `fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in test.gif`. What should I do to add any binary file, which could have any characters inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, git's implementation to handle EOL formats is a PAAAAAAIN. I would ask git not to do anything related to EOL format. That is done by adding `* -text` in .git/info/attributes. Not sure how that will affect binary files, though.